# Visual Studio debugger "snapshots"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Quite often I use debugger to step into unknown and discover 3rdparty objects. VS debugger does great job of displaying the internals of anything. The problem here is when I hit a breakpoint I'd like to "snapshot" a variable with all those members debugger shows as a tree, stop debugging and continue writing code looking at the snapshot. Is that possible?

Comment: The feature is called "Edit and Continue".  It is very unclear why it isn't enabled for you.  You could also simply copy/paste the entire tree into a text editor.  Click the first line, shift+click the last line and press Ctrl+C.

Comment: Edit&Continue doesn't work for 64bit builds